# MPAndroidChart Alignment of xAxis

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Can anyone help me with why my alignment is off for the xAxis. I want the points to be aligned with each of the respective text labels (the days of the week)

Here is the picture of what the chart looks like: [GRAPH PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5EVj.png)

and the code that produced it

```
private void setupChart() {
    final ArrayList<Entry> points = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add the values into the graph
    points.add(new Entry(1,  17));
    points.add(new Entry(2,  14));
    points.add(new Entry(3,  10));
    points.add(new Entry(4,  2));
    points.add(new Entry(5,  20));
    //Format the dataset to look nice
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(points, "Experiments");
    lineDataSet.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN);
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(5);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(10);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(3);

    //Add the LineDataSet to the DataSets
    final ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(lineDataSet);

    final LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
    chart.setData(lineData);
    //Format the chart nicely
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDrawBorders(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setExtraBottomOffset(10);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);

    //Get the XAxis of the grid
    XAxis xaxis = chart.getXAxis();
    //Format the xAxis
    final String[] dateStrings = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "THU", "Fri"};
    xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xaxis.setLabelCount(5);

    xaxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-8);
    xaxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return dateStrings[(int) value];
        }
    });
}
```

I am using com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2 in my dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Use below code.

```
xAxis.setLabelCount(5, true);
```

And, you can find implementation code on Library file.

```
public void setLabelCount(int count, boolean force) {
    setLabelCount(count);
    mForceLabels = force;
}
```

The "force" parameter determines whether to recalculate the label position.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line :

```
xaxis.setLabelCount(5);
```

Add below lines:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
```